# Outlook 365 search putting spaces in my "exact" search term

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

When I search my current mailbox for "newglass" I am getting results for all terms within that query. It is finding emails with "New Glass", "Glass" and "New"

I have seen post [Outlook exact search not working?](https://superuser.com/questions/447723/outlook-exact-search-not-working) but that does not answer the question.

According to official Microsoft docs "newglass" should only find emails with exactly that term in it. https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to search for an exact string, you must use quotation marks. When testing on my side, search results return correctly.

What type of email account did you set up? Exchange, POP3 or IMAP?

Have you tried using Advanced Search? Does it work?

The search function may have some problems. We can rebuild index to check the result. Please go to Control Panel > Indexing Options > advanced > Rebuild.

Also [repair your account data file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253) which could help.

Search issue was frequently discussed. You can check the step in this thread which discussed in TechNet forum:[search in outlook for email is not working](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d46f7047-90db-416c-908c-db63fd70a029/search-in-outlook-for-email-is-not-working?forum=outlook)

[Fixing Instant Search](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/47)

Comment: It is setup with IMAP. I have rebuilt the index and also repaired the pst file but now it finds nothing for the search term "newglass" with or without quotes. I have restarted outlook and windows. There is an email called newglass@domain.com that we're searching for, but now nothing comes up.

Comment: I think you can try typing from:newglass@domain.com to search it.

Comment: If issue still persists, you may create a new profile